# using CUTE in Eclipse: fatal error: boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, plugins

I'm a absolute newbie in Eclipse at least when it comes to using C++. Now I've found this Plugin for testing and followed the "instructions" (yeah well i created a cute project). When i try to build the sample Project i get the following error:

> ```
> fatal error: boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp: No such file or directory
> ```

the faliure is in file cute_determine_traits.h in the Project/cute directory where all of CUTE's includes are. The line it the program crashe is this one:

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp>
```

Actually i don't have any idea what I'm supposed to do.. I'd be very very happy for some easy instructions how to fix this! I'm using Eclipse c++.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I found the issue. I installed boost the wrong way. It worked as soon as i ran the bootstrap.bat using mingw. I followed this Video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDVRrSzsqco and then my includes worked.
Thanks everybody! :)

Comment: What kind of OS do you use?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geetings.

I had the same problem minutes ago. I realized I haven't install boost library when I was installing cute plug-in (boost can be found when you go to *Help->Install New Software*... and once you write the address http://www.cute-test.com/updatesite in "Work with" then choose *CUTE Optional Features->Boost For CUTE*).

Or maybe i haven't choosen the "Copy Boost headers into project" option... Anyways, I think both can solved your issue too.

Farewell!

Comment: This is definetely the easier way! Thanks for the reply!